# What is it called when you're developing a web application where every url has its own php file

Tags: terminology

What is it called when you aren't using an MVC framework and each URL has it's own file associated with it.  I want to say it's model 0 or class 0 but I haven't been able to find anything useful via Google. :-)

Comment: It's called an application where every url has its own PHP file.

Comment: Even in a MVC app , the requests can finally end up to different service classes based on the URL , just that it has to pass through the controller .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the Model 1 architecture in Java . Perhaps I have heard PHP developers referring to it as Monolithic architecture .

Comment: "mon·o·lith·ic  /ˌmänəˈliTHik/ Adjective: Formed of a single large block of stone."   I would call it _anything_ except monolithic!